# How to calculate map bounds without javascript

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I have a list of coordinates which will be considered as a center point of the map.

I need to calculate bounds of the map at zoom level 16 using only C# (no javascript no map object).

Is this possible?

Please advise.

Comment: All you need is math, this is independent of language.

Comment: Yes I know but do you have an example of a math? Please advise

Comment: just find the minimum and maximum of x,y in a loop. that gives you the bounding rectangle. not sure what you mean "zoom level 16" though.

Comment: I assume "zoom level 16" is the zoom level of the google maps. What you want to do implies very complicated maps and informaction you can only get in JavaScript. **Why are you wanting to do this in c#"?**

Comment: I am working on a website scrubbing project and the particular website uses google map which sends requests to the server which includes map bounds. I do have list of center points and need to generate bounds for each.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I wanted. I have not written this class personal and found in somewhere here and I don't remember so the credit goes X person! Provided Latitude and Longitude and a radius in KM gives a bounding box. Somewhat what GMap gives on viewport Bounds.

```
            public class GlobalMercator
            {
                public class MapPoint
                {
                    public double Longitude { get; set; } // In Degrees
                    public double Latitude { get; set; } // In Degrees
                }

                public class BoundingBox
                {
                    public MapPoint MinPoint { get; set; }
                    public MapPoint MaxPoint { get; set; }
                }

                // Semi-axes of WGS-84 geoidal reference
                private const double WGS84_a = 6378137.0; // Major semiaxis [m]
                private const double WGS84_b = 6356752.3; // Minor semiaxis [m]

                // 'halfSideInKm' is the half length of the bounding box you want in kilometers.
                public static BoundingBox GetBoundingBox(MapPoint point, double halfSideInKm)
                {
                    // Bounding box surrounding the point at given coordinates,
                    // assuming local approximation of Earth surface as a sphere
                    // of radius given by WGS84
                    var lat = Deg2rad(point.Latitude);
                    var lon = Deg2rad(point.Longitude);
                    var halfSide = 1000 * halfSideInKm;

                    // Radius of Earth at given latitude
                    var radius = WGS84EarthRadius(lat);
                    // Radius of the parallel at given latitude
                    var pradius = radius * Math.Cos(lat);

                    var latMin = lat - halfSide / radius;
                    var latMax = lat + halfSide / radius;
                    var lonMin = lon - halfSide / pradius;
                    var lonMax = lon + halfSide / pradius;

                    return new BoundingBox
                    {
                        MinPoint = new MapPoint { Latitude = Rad2deg(latMin), Longitude = Rad2deg(lonMin) },
                        MaxPoint = new MapPoint { Latitude = Rad2deg(latMax), Longitude = Rad2deg(lonMax) }
                    };
                }

                // degrees to radians
                private static double Deg2rad(double degrees)
                {
                    return Math.PI * degrees / 180.0;
                }

                // radians to degrees
                private static double Rad2deg(double radians)
                {
                    return 180.0 * radians / Math.PI;
                }

                // Earth radius at a given latitude, according to the WGS-84 ellipsoid [m]
                private static double WGS84EarthRadius(double lat)
                {
                    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius
                    var An = WGS84_a * WGS84_a * Math.Cos(lat);
                    var Bn = WGS84_b * WGS84_b * Math.Sin(lat);
                    var Ad = WGS84_a * Math.Cos(lat);
                    var Bd = WGS84_b * Math.Sin(lat);
                    return Math.Sqrt((An * An + Bn * Bn) / (Ad * Ad + Bd * Bd));
                }  
            }
```